# Соединение через udp windows и linux машин

Tags: qt, udp

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Здравствуйте! Передо мной возникла задача соединиться с серверной частью для моего фронт-енда. Решили использовать qt т.к. меньше возни с сокетами, использовали мультикастные пакеты. Вся трудность состоит в том, что во времятестирования на 2 windows машинах нам удалось проверить связь. Передача сообщений прошла корректно. В случае же когда соединение происходило между Linux и Windows машинами, qt ничего не отображал (не отрабатывает сигнал на пришедший пакет, будто его и нет) , хотя wireshark показывал что передача сообщений проходит и он детектирует их. Прикрепляю код простого тестового приемника и принтскрин wireshark.

```
#include <QtWidgets>
#include <QtNetwork>

#include "receiver.h"

Receiver::Receiver(QWidget *parent)
: QDialog(parent)
{
  groupAddress = QHostAddress("226.1.1.1");//QHostAddress("239.255.43.21");

statusLabel = new QLabel(tr("Listening for multicasted messages"));
quitButton = new QPushButton(tr("&Quit"));

udpSocket = new QUdpSocket(this);
udpSocket->bind(QHostAddress::AnyIPv4, 50100, QUdpSocket::ReuseAddressHint);//udpSocket->bind(QHostAddress::AnyIPv4, 45454, QUdpSocket::ShareAddress);
udpSocket->joinMulticastGroup(groupAddress);

connect(udpSocket, SIGNAL(readyRead()),
        this, SLOT(processPendingDatagrams()));
connect(quitButton, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(close()));

QHBoxLayout *buttonLayout = new QHBoxLayout;
buttonLayout->addStretch(1);
buttonLayout->addWidget(quitButton);
buttonLayout->addStretch(1);

QVBoxLayout *mainLayout = new QVBoxLayout;
mainLayout->addWidget(statusLabel);
mainLayout->addLayout(buttonLayout);
setLayout(mainLayout);

setWindowTitle(tr("Multicast Receiver"));
}

void Receiver::processPendingDatagrams()
 {
while (udpSocket->hasPendingDatagrams()) {
    QByteArray datagram;
    datagram.resize(udpSocket->pendingDatagramSize());
    udpSocket->readDatagram(datagram.data(), datagram.size());
    statusLabel->setText(tr("Received datagram: \"%1\"").arg(datagram.data()));
}
}
```